# Break one MySQL table into two (export contents)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please help me to **export contents** MySQL table into two. I tried a lot, but the results are poor.

Initial table:

```
product_id  int(11) //id of some product    
feature_id  int(11) //id of the feature (like: color)            
option_name varchar(1024)   utf8_general_ci // variant of the feature (like: blue)
PRIMARY(product_id, feature_id)
```

(DESC: this is the table that stores option name(variant) for certain option connected to certain product)

But this is not good (there is no need to specify option_name for each product, better to specify option_id) and so I logically broke it into two but I cannot export in contents right.

1) options

```
id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT       
feature_id  int(11)         
option_name varchar(1024)   utf8_general_ci
```

DESC: it stores just option_name and id and feature, to which it is connected

2) products_options

```
id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT   Показать больше операций
product_id  int(11)         
feature_id  int(11) 
option_id   int(11)
```

DESC: it stores option_id and product_id and feature_id, to which it is connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO options (feature_id, option_name) VALUES (SELECT feature_id, option_name FROM initial_table);
```

Next make some script (on php maybe?) to fill products_options with `option_ids`, because u need find `options.option_id` by `Initial_table.option_name`, but mysql doesn't support joins sub queries.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I see that it's the solution I need!

Comment: only I see that I need SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Also I made it without scripts, just with two subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery

```
INSERT INTO options (feature_id, option_name) VALUES
      (SELECT feature_id, option_name FROM initial_table);
```